# OpenGL camera question, how far back can it render?

Tags: opengl, sdl

I'm working on a very simple program that draws 2 planes. A ground plane and a back ground plane.

I'm attempting to draw both planes using these points ordered in X, Y, Z coordinates.

background plane

- point 1  100.000002 100.000002 100.000002
- point 2  -100.000002 100.000002 100.000002
- point 3  -50.000001 -23.000001 100.000002
- point 4  50.000001 -23.000001 100.000002

ground plane

- point 1  -50.000001 -23.000001 100.000002
- point 2  50.000001 -23.000001 100.000002
- point 3  0.352941 -0.352941 0.352941
- point 4  -0.352941 -0.352941 0.352941

My GL Setup:

- OpenGL lighting is off.
- I'm drawing with GL_QUAD in the order the points are listed.
- I have not assigned surface normals to the quads.
- Camera is centered at (0,0,0) with the Y+ as "up" and the Z axis as depth.

The ground plane renders perfectly (just a sheet of gray), but the background plane isn't rendering at all. So I have to ask:

- Should I turn on lighting and compute surface normals?
- Do I need to fiddle with the camera and/or view frustrum to see the back plane (does OpenGL "drop off" at a distance of Z = 100+)?

Any help is appreciated. I'm using libSDL with OpenGL.

My OpenGL initialization code looks like this:

```
if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
    return false;
}

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);   

screenptr = SDL_SetVideoMode(swidth, sheight, sbpp, VIDEO_MODE_OPTIONS);

if( screenptr == NULL) {
    return false;
}

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
glClearDepth(1.0f);

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL); 
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
//gluPerspective(45.0f, SCREEN_WIDTH/SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 500.0f);
//gluPerspective( 45.0f, 1.0, 0.1f, 100.0f );
//glFrustum(-500.0f, 500.0f, -500.0f, 500.f, 0.1f, 500.f);
//glFrustum(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 5, 400);

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

if(glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I would guess that your far clipping plane is set at 100?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take a look at where you create your camera matrix (a call to glPerspective or something similar, I haven't used SDL) and set the near and far-plane to a value such that everything that you want a user to see is further away as the near plane, but closer as the far plane. Everything that is not in between the near and far plane is clipped.

Edit I looked it up, in SDL you create the view matrix like this:

```
/* Create our projection matrix with a 45 degree field of view
 * a width to height ratio of 1.0 and view from .1 to 100 infront of us */
perspective(projectionmatrix, 45.0, 1.0, 0.1, 100.0);
```

Don't ever set the near plane to 0 (will result in a devision by zero exception) or the far plane to Float.Max (might cause weird problems)

Also take a look at this view frustum picture for a perspective projection:
[image: view frustum]

Comment: Ray, great post! I initially tried gluPerspective (trying to keep to OpenGL API, using SDL for the Window/Keyboard/Mouse interface) and it didn't generate anything, so I removed it from my source. So I'm using whatever OpenGL is doing by default. I was able to get a textured plane to render...so I guess by default the frustrum is set to something < 100.0f. Interesting. I was wondering if I could try using glFrustum instead to define the scene?

Comment: @ct: gluPerspective actually is not OpenGL API. It's GLU, a helper library associated with but not part of OpenGL.

Comment: @RoyT. I was able to get the system to render something, though it required a called to gluViewPort before calling gluPerspective, I wasn't particularly pleased with the results (same issue with the backplane not rendering). So, it might be a quad facing issue?

Comment: Hey CT, what if you render the vertices of the quad as points, do you see them then? If so it's probably a winding (culling) issue, if not then it's probably an issue with camera matrix. And what happens if you place the quad closer, is there a certain point where you can see it and a point where you can't?

Comment: the backplane doesn't render but, i was able to get 2 points to render they were the points closest to the camera, the back 2 points didn't render. so maybe it's a culling issue. you think it's a far plane issue?

Comment: ah figured it out. you have to make 3 opengl calls in succession to get things to work somewhat correctly. glViewport, gluPerspective, and gluLookAt are called in that order. my surface is a little warped vertically but i figured that's an FOV problem. thanks again @RoyT. !

Answer (score 2):

How are you setting up your projection matrix? It should include some information about how far aware things can be rendered (often called the far plane distance), in your case you need this to be more than 100.

The second problem it could be is that if you are only rendering front-facing quads, then if your quad is back-facing it won't be rendered.

Comment: @JacksonPope I added my initialization code to the question. When I turn on gluPerspective OR glFrustrum, nothing renders. Will check the facing quad issue, do you have any references?

Comment: @ct: With the Identity matrix as your projection matrix the background will be beyond your far plane. Try using gluLookAt instead (it's a bit easier to get your head around to begin with).

Comment: @JacksonPope, thanks, gluLookAt was a lot easier to understand. I gave that a try and it's rendering, though, I'm still having the depth issue with the backgroundplane. I'll check out the facing issue.

Comment: @ct: To quickly check the facing, try swapping the order of vertices 2 and 4.

Comment: @JacksonPope, thanks again for the help! it turns out the surfaces are facing the right direction. I did some fiddling around with my OpenGL set up and fixed the view issues, I also found some numeric assumptions that were incorrect. Basically I thought that if the camera was at the origin and facing down -1.0Z, all points with a negative Z value would be in front of it...that intuition is not quite right :P so, after much fiddling, I was able to get was shooting for! thanks again for all your help!